# Convert all jpg to png files in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have a dataset with about 800 images and most are png with a few jpg files. The dataset is mounted in the drive of Google Colab. My question is I have this code below that helps with conversion, but it does not save the files in the images folder from the directory. How do I get the files to save in the original location in the loop?

```
directory = r'/content/drive/MyDrive/images/images/' 
for filename in os.listdir(directory): 
    if filename.endswith('.jpg'): 
        prefix = filename.split('.jpg')[0]
        # im = Image.open(filename)
        os.rename(filename, prefix+'.png')  
    else: 
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
directory = r'/content/drive/MyDrive/images/images/' 

files = os.listdir(directory)


# Then you rename the files 
for file_name in files:
    # You give the full path of the file
    old_name = os.path.join(directory, file_name)

    # You CHANGE the extension
    new_name = old_name.replace('.jpg', '.png')
    os.rename(old_name, new_name)
```

Comment: To answer @SenthurLP comment, this code is perfectly working on google colab :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that when iterating `os.listdir()` it will have only the file names like `image_1.png` but not the entire path like `'/content/drive/MyDrive/images/images/image_1.png'` which is essential for saving the images.

So change the line `os.rename(filename, prefix+'.png')` into  `os.rename(os.path.join(directory, filename), os.path.join(directory, prefix+'.png'))`

And it works

Comment: Excellent - that piece of code did the trick. Thank you so much! I'm having an issue after the conversion in the next part when I loop through reading the image files I get this error message: "ValueError: invalid PNG header"

Comment: I was able to get it to work, thanks!